# How to get the number of (currently) established TCP connections of a specific port of a node in prometheus (kubernetes monitoring)

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

When managing a cluster, I might want to know how many tcp connections to one port on each node. This can help me to alert if some node's tcp connections number to some port are too many.

I can use `netstat -nat | grep -i "22" | wc -l` on a linux node to see how many connections to port 22. But I'm looking for a method that can do this and export the metric on prometheus.

**node_exporter** has a metric **node_netstat_Tcp_CurrEstab** that can show tcp connections total number. But it has only a label named **instance** to show the total number on that node. But I want to check by a label like **port**.

In a word, I want to track tcp connections on node 192.168.1.1, port 22.

Anybody knows is there a metric in **node_exporter** or is there a exporter can do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible through default metrics: netstat collector shows a summary with no detailing. From [official docs](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter#enabled-by-default):

> Exposes network statistics from `/proc/net/netstat`. This is the same information as `netstat -s`.

But you can always utilize a [textfile collector](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter#textfile-collector), and add a script to your cron that will update number of open metrics.

I believe you'll need a command like this:

```bash
echo 'custom_established_connections{port="22"}' $(netstat -nat|grep -P ':22\b.*ESTABLISHED$'|wc -l) > /path/to/directory/role.prom.$$
```

Comment: thx for reply, this is a quite tricky way to collect what I want. Anyway, is there any substitution for node_exporter? If there is an exporter already did this, then I can only deploy it on my node and config my prometheus to scrape metrics from it.

Comment: @54vault, not that I'm aware of, no.